# Unable to drag and drop a item created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

This is my first post in StackOverFlow and i am just a newbie in coding as well. I am trying to create a effect where I will draw a card from the deck.(In this case, i just create a rectangle-Monsters(Red) as a placeholder) and drag that card and drop it on a targetted rectangle area.

When I manually create a card, as shown below in the HTML code, that rectangle can be dragged and dropped into the targetted rectangle area. However, when i create a rectangle using Javascript, the rectangle created using Javascript can be dragged and the "hover" effect works, but it cannot be dropped into the targetted rectangle area.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<img id="deck" class="cards board6" src="../images/Deck.png" onclick="drawCard()">

<section id="dropBox">
</section>

<section id="hand">
</section>

<img id="card1" class="cards hand1" src="../images/Monsters(Red).png">
```

This is my Javascript Code:

```
//Drag & Drop
function doFirst() {

var card1 = document.getElementById('card1');

card1.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
var dropBox = document.getElementById('dropBox');
dropBox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter,false);
dropBox.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave,false);
dropBox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);

dropBox.addEventListener("drop", dropped,false);
}

function dragEnter(e){ // Hover In Effect
e.preventDefault();
dropBox.style.background="SkyBlue";
dropBox.style.border="3px solid red";
}

function dragLeave(e){ //Hover Out Effect
e.preventDefault();
dropBox.style.background="White";
dropBox.style.border="3px solid blue";
}

function startDrag(e) {
var code = '<img id="card1" class="cards hand1" src="../images/Monsters(Red).png">';
e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function dropped(e) {
e.preventDefault();
dropBox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
dropBox.style.background="White";
dropBox.style.border="3px solid blue";
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);

//Dealing Of Cards
document.getElementById("hand");

var noCardsInHand = 0; //Initialization
function drawCard(e) {
if (noCardsInHand === 0) {
  alert("Card Drawn");
hand.innerHTML = '<img id="card1" class="handCards1 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'>';
noCardsInHand++;
alert(noCardsInHand);
}

else if (noCardsInHand === 1) {
  alert("Card Drawn");
hand.innerHTML = '<img id="card1" class="handCards1 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'><img id="card1" class="handCards2 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'>';
noCardsInHand++;
alert(noCardsInHand);
}
else if (noCardsInHand === 2) {
  alert("Card Drawn");
hand.innerHTML = '<img id="card1" class="handCards1 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'><img id="card1" class="handCards2 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'><img id="card1" class="handCards2 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'>';
noCardsInHand++;
alert(noCardsInHand);
}
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gsvwncmu/2)

Comment: can you please add a code snippet in the app, you can use the one from stackoverflow or jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gsvwncmu/2/

Comment: I added it to the demo link in your question

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine you just need to have it run after the html elements are rendered otherwise it won't find anything to bind to

https://jsfiddle.net/gsvwncmu/3/

in the jsfiddle in the javascript area there are a gear at the top this will drop the following and select ondomready

[image: ondomready]

now to do this in your code you'll either have to move your script to the end of the body tag, or add the script file as deferred

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="./jsfile.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="deck" class="cards board6" src="http://i63.tinypic.com/f40188.png" onclick="drawCard()">

    <section id="dropBox">
    </section>

    <section id="hand">
    </section>

    <img id="card1" class="cards hand1" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2h520bd.png">
    <img class="cards hand2" src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2h520bd.png">
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
//Drag & Drop
function doFirst() {
var card1 = document.getElementById('card1');
card1.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
var dropBox = document.getElementById('dropBox');
dropBox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter,false);
dropBox.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave,false);
dropBox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
dropBox.addEventListener("drop", dropped,false);
}

function dragEnter(e){ // Hover In Effect
e.preventDefault();
dropBox.style.background="SkyBlue";
dropBox.style.border="3px solid red";
}

function dragLeave(e){ //Hover Out Effect
e.preventDefault();
dropBox.style.background="White";
dropBox.style.border="3px solid blue";
}

function startDrag(e) {
var code = '<img id="card1" class="cards hand1" src="../images/Monsters(Red).png">';
e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function dropped(e) {
e.preventDefault();
dropBox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
dropBox.style.background="White";
dropBox.style.border="3px solid blue";
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);

//Dealing Of Cards
document.getElementById("hand");

var noCardsInHand = 0; //Initialization
function drawCard(e) {
if (noCardsInHand === 0) {
alert("Card Drawn");
hand.innerHTML = '<img id="card1" class="handCards1 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'>';
noCardsInHand++;
alert(noCardsInHand);
}

else if (noCardsInHand === 1) {
alert("Card Drawn");
hand.innerHTML = '<img id="card1" class="handCards1 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'><img id="card1" class="handCards2 cards" src=\'../images/Monsters(Red).png\'>';
noCardsInHand++;
alert(noCardsInHand);
}

}
```

CSS

```
.cards {
            width: 55px;
            height: 82.5px;
        }

        .board6 {
            margin-left: 3%;
        }

        .hand1 {
            margin-left: 9%;
        }

        .hand2 {
            margin-left: 1%;
        }

        #dropBox {
            width: 535px;
            height: 82.5px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 3px solid blue;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }

        #hand {
            width: 535px;
            height: 82.5px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 3px solid red;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }
```

Comment: Currently, im running my html, css, js files separately. If so, what should i do?

Comment: I edited the answer please mark as answered if you think it helped

Comment: My original idea was that when i press the purple rectangle, a red rectangle appears in the red box(which it does when the code is ran). However, i am unable to drag the newly created red rectangle into the blue box.

Comment: to move DOM elements on the screen you'll need to be able to select them by id, you are using the same id 'card1', for all, also the items that are added later from drawing the card need to have dragging event on them too